# Linear optimization doesn't respect constraint

Tags: python, optimization, scipy, linear-programming

I have a simple linear problem that needs to respect a specific boundary and constraint, but when running `scipy.linprog` the constraint isn't respected.

For my objective function I'm using the values in a column as my coefficients.

```
c = [-df['A'][0], 
              -df['A'][1],
              -df['A'][2],
              -df['A'][3],
              -df['A'][4],
              -df['A'][5],
              -df['A'][6],
              -df['A'][7],
              -df['A'][8],
              -df['A'][9]
              ]
```

For my constraint i'm using the values of another column as my coefficients

```
A = [df['B'][0], 
              df['B'][1],
              df['B'][2],
              df['B'][3],
              df['B'][4],
              df['B'][5],
              df['B'][6],
              df['B'][7],
              df['B'][8],
              df['B'][9]
              ]
```

And the inequality value is this division

```
b = [np.sum(df2['C'] * df2['D'] * df2['E']) / (9.12*12)]
res = linprog(c=c, A_ub=A, b_ub=b, bounds=bounds, options={'dips': True, 'tol': 1e-8})
```

My objective function is to find the best vector that maximize the sum of `df['A']*vector` in the same time that i respect the sum of `df['B']*vector = b`.

I also tried using 'simplex' and 'interior-point'.

When I tried this implementation using simplex I got the result:

```
 message: Optimization terminated successfully.
 success: True
  status: 0
     fun: -104315467.86366615
       x: [ 1.000e+00  1.000e+00  1.000e+00  1.000e+00  1.000e+00
            1.000e+00  1.000e+00  1.000e+00  1.000e+00  1.000e+00]
     nit: 11
```

Which isn't optimal, nor does it respect my constraint.

Comment: Can you provide your dataframe as plain text please? `print(df.to_dict('list'))`. and your `bounds`. Why do you have to dataframes (are indexes aligned?)?